# Adding Product Variations to product page

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I am working on http://fitboxmeals.com/order/ and I would like to use this snippet of code in my woocommerce theme's function.php so my product variations show up on the meals products page.

```html
if ( ! function_exists( ‘woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart’ ) ) { function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() { global $product; if ($product->product_type == "variable") { woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart(); } else { woocommerce_get_template(
'loop/add-to-cart.php' ); } } }
```

The code works but now when I add a product to the cart, I would like to reset the variations so the user can select those variations again for the same product or a different one after a product has been added to the cart.

```html
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly global $woocommerce, $product, $post; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
  <?php if ( ! empty( $available_variations ) ) : ?>
  <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <?php $loop=0 ; foreach ( $attributes as $name=>$options ) : $loop++; ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">
          <label for="<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>">
            <?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
          <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">
            <option value="">
              <?php echo __( 'Choose an option', ETHEME_DOMAIN ) ?>&hellip;</option>
            <?php if ( is_array( $options ) ) { if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) { $selected_value=$ _REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ]; } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) { $selected_value=$
            selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ]; } else { $selected_value='' ; } // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) { $orderby=w c_attribute_orderby( $name ); switch ( $orderby ) { case 'name' : $args=a
            rray( 'orderby'=>'name', 'hide_empty' => false, 'menu_order' => false ); break; case 'id' : $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'menu_order' => false, 'hide_empty' => false ); break; case 'menu_order' : $args = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => false ); break; } $terms = get_terms( $name, $args ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) continue; echo '
            <option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '"
            ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>'; } } else { foreach ( $options as $option ) { echo '
            <option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '"
            ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>'; } } } ?>
          </select>
          <?php if ( sizeof($attributes)==$ loop ) echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">' . __( 'Clear selection', ETHEME_DOMAIN ) . '</a>'; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

  <div class="single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' ); ?>

    <div class="single_variation"></div>

    <div class="variations_button">
      <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
      <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button big active alt"><span><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" />

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>
  </div>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

  <?php else : ?>

  <p class="stock out-of-stock">
    <?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', ETHEME_DOMAIN ); ?>
  </p>

  <?php endif; ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

I hope this helps, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Second para is difficult to follow, in part due to missing punctuation.

Comment: Hi Roamer-1888, I just updated the post. Hopefully it makes a little more since than before. Thank you for taking a look at it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: RoccRocc, unfortunately I'm not the right person to answer your question. I'm just doing some quality control on the wording. Much better after the edit though I'm still finding it hard to visualise. I think a further improvement would be to put more meat on "reset the variations" - what does that actually mean?

Comment: Currently on this page http://fitboxmeals.com/product-category/meals/ I have products listed with the option to "Choose a selection." After you chose a selection, it shows the QTY and the Add To Cart button for that selection. After you have added the product to the cart, I would like the product option to reset to "Choose a selection".

Comment: I think I get it. "Add to Cart" is designed to add an item to the cart, then redirect to the cart. You have found a way to suppress the redirect but the page is left in a poor state and needs to be cleaned up by resetting `<select>` all menus to their default "Choose an option" option and hiding the "Add to Cart" popup. Yes?

Comment: Yes that's it. I found a temporary solution by using a form location.reload() but I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: I think the javascript/jQuery to tidy the page (without reloading) will be quite trivial. It's just a question of knowing where to put it in such a large ocean of scripts.

Comment: I agree. Currently it does refresh the options but only because I set the delay for 350 milli-seconds. So, it takes two refreshes for it to show up in the cart.                                                           <form onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 350)" class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>" >

Answer (score 0):

Event handers should really be attached in javascript/jQuery, not as HTML attributes, but since your setTimeout works for you so should something like this :

```
<form onsubmit="
    $.ajax({
        url: location.href,
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).then(function() {
        //tidy the page
        $('select.whatever').each(function() {
            this.selectedIndex = 0;
        }).eq(0).trigger('change');
    });
    return false;" class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>" >
```

I've never tried defining quite such an extensive event handler in that way but, AFAIK, it stands a chance of working (when debugged).

You will need to change 'whatever' to the classname applied to your product variation select menus. Currently they appear to have identical ids, so you should be able to simply change `id=` to `class=` in the `<select>` tags.

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a whirl and see where it takes me. Thank you Roamer-1888.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin works flawlessly for table of variations on product page:
http://www.eggplantstudios.ca/woocommerce-product-variation-add-cart-grid/